# Symfony Form vs. Serializer for RESTful API

Tags: php, rest, symfony, symfony-forms

Should I use `Form` component or `Serializer` component to bind request data to domain object for a RESTful API project?

I feel that `Form` is difficult to customize and not naturally fit with RESTful.

Some guys use `Serializer` for object binding instead of Form. Eg: http://www.slideshare.net/dlondero/rest-in-practiceenglish

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572261/symfony-restful-post-jmsserializerbundle-vs-symfony-form-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After over a year, I suggest anyone working with RESTful Web Services in Symfony should use `Serialize Component` instead of `Form Component` because of customization and simplicity.

With `Serializer Component` you can easily customize request format, error message...